# How to get the position of a random number generated in a python list.?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a numeric list. I need pick a random number in a numeric list and know position number found in list.
random.choice(name_list) just find a random number but I am at the same time in need of a random number position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also get the index and the random number in one operation using enumerate()

```
index,number = random.choice(list(enumerate(a)))
```

This not very efficient however and, if you're doing this often or on a very big list, you should do it in two steps

```
index   = random.randrange(len(a))
number  = a[index]
```

Answer (score 3):

generate random indexes to use instead.

```
import random
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
rand_num = random.randrange(len(a))
print(a[rand_num])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
sample_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
# this should be work for multiple same value indexes
# EX: sample_list = [1,2,3,2,2] 
# if random number is 2 than below code will print indexes 1, 3, 4
random_number = random.choice(sample_list)
for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(sample_list) if x == random_number]:
    print(i) # print the indexes or random number
```

Comment: its working if we have not repeat number in list. but i have

Comment: @Prance, What I wanted to say that is above code find the position/positions of random number, whatever you need.